# How can we implement cucumber in an ant project(DDT)?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, ant, cucumber

I would like to ask how can we implement cucumber in a DDT framework using ant build in Eclipse? Also is using selenium, soap, TestNg.
What jars do I need to bring in the build.xml?
Under which folders should I implement cucumber with Gherkin language?

Thanks!!!

I'm in the progress of implementing something new for our current framework which is very outdated, so first this I would like to try is to see if this is even possible to implement cucumber bdd in an ant project that uses DDT mostly.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.